# Java: characters

Tags: java, char, output, character

The assignment:

User inputs a number(1-26) and then a phrase(A-Z). My code needs to then output a new phrase by adding the new number to their original input.

For example, the user inputs 2 and A, the new output should be C. Or, the user inputs 4 and B, the new output should be F.

Issue: I am unsure how to get the correct output for the letter given by the user, or if I've set everything else up accurately.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
char letter;

System.out.println("Hello! \n");
System.out.println("Please select a number between 1-26!");
int user = input.nextInt(); 

if(user < 1 && user > 26)
{
    System.out.println("Sorry, your number is invalid.");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Now, enter a letter!");
    letter = input.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: "`(user < 1 && user > 260)`" What numbers do you think satisfy that condition? (And shouldn't it be 26, anyway?)

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code"_ are considered off-topic.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: @Jim Garrison, Ops, too late for that, already answered. Stackoverflow is way too harsh on beginners when the question takes like less than a minute to answer.

Comment: @parsecer If you believe answering a specific user's question is the primary goal of StackOverflow then you have not understood the site's purpose.  Providing assistance to the person asking the question is a minor goal compared to the multiplying effect of helping potentially _thousands_ of _future_ readers.  A good question is well-written, with all the necessary information, and applies to a situation others might encounter.  Debugging code that contains multiple trivial errors does not constitute appropriate use of this site.

Comment: yep, should be 26, it was a typo, thanks for pointing that out. It's correct in my original code. 

@Jim Garrison And sorry, I thought this was a community aimed at helping each other, beginning programmers included. My bad. I'll show myself out.

Comment: @Jim Garrison, Well, obviously there are so many users already on this site that answering even not-so-worthy questions is no bother for anyone. Those who asked the question get their answer, those who answered - satisfaction at helping at the very least. The question can later be deleted if it's duplicate or too naive. Everyone gains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like the `while` loop here to wait for the right input instead of terminating the program. Also, if you want only uppercase A-Z to appear, remember to include upper limit on `letter` or `user`.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
char letter;

System.out.println("Hello! \n");
System.out.println("Please select a number between 1-26!");
int user = input.nextInt(); 
while (user<1 || user>260)  {
   System.out.println("Sorry, your number is invalid.");
    user=input.nextInt();
}
 System.out.println("Now, enter a letter!");
 letter = input.next().charAt(0);
 while (letter<0 || user+letter>90)  {
     System.out.println("The letter should not be negative and too high");
     letter=input.next().charAt(0);
 }
 System.out.println((char) (user+letter));
}
```

Comment: I feel kinda stupid, it seems so straight forward now that I see it. I'm also going to add another loop so that it continues to repeat unless the user chooses to exit. Thank you so much! :D

Comment: @KJo, That's how you always feel after looking at a solution ;) You are welcome and good luck learning Java!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in a easy way >> just cast summing of int value to char value to char like this

```
System.out.println((char)('A'+2));
```

Hint : change

```
if(user < 1 && user > 260)
```

To

```
if(user < 1 || user > 26)
```

Comment: Note that you can do it without explicit casting: `letter += user`.

Comment: if he did that will print out ASCII code for in instead of Letter
if he not use = sign ^^

Comment: without an equal sign? 
try you run this line 
        System.out.println(('a'+2));
it print out 99 instead of c

Comment: Yep. And that's why I didn't say `letter + user`, but rather `letter += user`.

Comment: i said if he doesn't use = sign will get ASCII code review my word ^^

Comment: Hint: "if(user < 1 && user > 26)"  is true as he need to print out error message if user enter a wrong number and it would be less than 1 and greater than 26

Comment: "if he did that will print out ASCII code for in instead of Letter if he not use = sign" I am making a very precise statement about using `+=`; if you don't use `=`, sure, it does something different; but that's not what I said to do.

Comment: "it would be less than 1 and greater than 26" Can you give an example of a number that is both less than 1 and greater than 26?

Comment: if user enter number '-1' then char 'a' what would be the output?

Comment: "`Now, enter a letter`". -1 is less than 1, but not greater than 26.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry it must be || not && I'll edit it now thanks <3